# Split Perl string by full stop and use the elements as variables

Tags: perl

I have a string which is separated by full stops and I want to use the separated elements as variables.

For example, if I have

```
$string = "This.is.a.string";
```

When I say

```
print $1;
```

I want this to output "This", or print $2 will output "is", etc.

I have tried

```
$elements = split(/\\./, $string);
print $1;
```

but no luck so far.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why do you **want** `$1` instead of the array elements?

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "This.is.a.string";
my @output = split /\./, $string;

print $output[0]; # this will print 'this' where $output[1] will print 'is'
```

or you can even be fancy and print the string by replacing dot with space.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "This.is.a.string";
$string =~  s/\./ /g;

print $string; # this will print 'This is a string'
```

On a side note, just to show you where you went wrong.

```
split /\\./, $string;
```

a split is define between two forward slashes, but special characters needs to be escaped by a backslash, you are currently escaping a backslash and not the dot. it should be

```
split /\./, $string;
```

secondly, you have not defined $1 so it does not know what $1 is. if you wanted to use it in your string you would need to tell it what $1 is for instance.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "This.is.a.string";
my @output = split /\./, $string;

$1 = $output[1];
print $1;
```

but this is unnecessary, just showing you the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
@elements = split(/\./, $string); print $elements[0];
```

`@elements` is an array and `$elements[0]` is the first element of that array.

Comment: You are confusing lists and arrays. `@` is the sigil for an array.

Comment: @MattJacob In perl a list and an array are the same thing, I;ve always called the lists.

Comment: @EssexBoy A list and an array are not the same thing. You can assign a list to an array (or hash), but a list is much different. The `split` returns a list, and then you're assigning it to an array. See [this](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl)

Comment: I think it's a bit academic. technically @stevieb is right but I'm not sure when it ever matters. it's like the difference between a scalar and an integer. a scalar can be a variable for an int like an array is a variable for a list. basically one is a container and the other is a value. this is all intuitive to a Perl programmer but it always helps to use correct terminology.

Comment: @beasy it matters in many aspects. Saying a scalar is an integer is just as wrong as saying an array or hash is a list. They are two fundamentally different things as far as the interpreter is concerned. In C, you wouldn't call an array a 'list'. In Python, you wouldn't call a list an 'array'. Intuitive or not, it is pretty important as you said to use correct terminology relative to the language you are using. If it's an "academic" thing, academics should be teaching the proper terminology for the language that is being discussed. This is not just a Perl thing.

Comment: @stevieb I accept the distinction, I will be more careful with my choice of words in the future :)